# Como passar valor de input com método POST usando Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, post, get

Estou tentando passar certos valores de um `input` através do método POST usando Angular, porém não estou conseguindo passar esses valores na URL e nem mesmo pegar eles no servidor. Alguém poderia me ajudar a solucionar esse problema?

Detalhe, para cada botão que eu clicar eu tenho que passar os dois valores do input + valor do botão clicado (operação).

**Formulário**

```
<form id="form" ng-controller="Controller">
  <input id="val1" name="val1" ng-model="val1" placeholder="Valor 1" type="text">
  <input id="val2" name="val2" ng-model="val2" placeholder="Valor 2" type="text">
  <input id="operacao" name="operacao" type="hidden" value="0">
  <input id="soma" type="button" value="soma" ng-click="doClick(val1, val2)">
  <input id="sub" type="button" value="sub">
  <input id="mult" type="button" value="mult">
  <input id="divs" type="button" value="divs">
  <input id="resultado" type="text"><br>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
.controller("Controller", function($scope, operacaoService) { $scope.model = {};
  $scope.doClick = function(operacao) {
    $scope.model.operacao = operacao;
    operacaoService.postOperacao($scope.model).success(function(data, status) {
      $scope.valores = data.result;
      console.log(data.result);
    }).error(function(data, status) {
      console.log("erro", status);
    });
  };
})
```

**Service**

```
module.factory('operacaoService', function($http) {

  var postOperacao = function(model) {

    return $http({
      url: "/operacoes",
      method: "post",
      params: model
    });
  };

  return {
    postOperacao: postOperacao
  };
});
```

---

**Servidor (Node.js)**

```
app.post('/operacoes', function(req, res) {

  var valores = req.query;
  var val1 = parseInt(valores.val1);
  var val2 = parseInt(valores.val2);
  var operacao = (valores.operacao);
  var result;

  if (operacao === "soma") {
    result = val1 + val2;
    res.send({
      result: result,
      val1: val1,
      val2: val2,
      operacao: operacao
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na chamada do ng-click você está passando ***val1, val2*** e na função recebe ***operacao*** 
Você poderia mandar :

```
 <input id="soma" type="button" value="soma" ng-click="doClick(val1, val2, operacao)">
```

Passando assim os 3 parametros que quer e pegando na dentro da função. Da forma que fez pegou apenas a operação. 
Ou ainda:

```
<input id="val1" name="val1" ng-model="model.val1" placeholder="Valor 1" type="text">
<input id="val2" name="val2" ng-model="model.val2" placeholder="Valor 2" type="text">
<input id="operacao" name="operacao" ng-model="model.operacao" type="hidden" value="0">
<input id="soma" type="button" value="soma" ng-click="doClick(model)">
```

e na função já passaria o model direto. Não testei o restante do seu código, mas vi que os valores não estavam sendo passados. De um console.log dentro da função para verificar se as informações estão passando corretamente

Answer (score 3):

Tente simplificar o seu método `$http`

```
$http.post(url, data, config); //Você não está usando configurações extras, então não use o 3º parâmetro
$http.post('/operacoes', model);
```

Se ainda assim não der certo, adicione um retorno para ver o que está acontecendo. Pode ser problema no servidor.

```
$http.post('/operacoes',model).then( 
    function(res) {console.log(res)}
);
```

Isso irá exibir o retorno no console.